# How to replace a word in string in a yml configuration file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, configuration, yaml

```
flows:
  default:
    - log: "Starting the dev deployment of latest image."
    - log: '${imageTag}'
```

The ${imageTag} variable in the above yml configuration is printing the artifact Id with snapshot version (i.e.. 0.0.10-SNAPSHOT-199). But I would like to replace the version without snapshot in it (i.e.. 0.0.10-199 ). Basically I need to replace the string containing SNAPSHOT to empty string. Can someone help me with syntax. I tried different syntax which didn't worked like shown below.

```
flows:
  default:
    - log: "Starting the dev deployment of latest image."
    - log: '${imageTag}.replace("-SNAPSHOT", "")'
```

Comment: I think your best bet would be to configure a helm chart: http://helm.sh/

Comment: Or, [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io) has the specific ability to [set image names and tags](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/images/).  That `flows:` doesn't sound like a standard Kubernetes YAML item, though.